# Getting primary email for using C2DM in android

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I want to use a C2DM which will allow my Java Server to send Data to Android phone. Since for
using C2DM each device need its gmail ID, my Question is that how can i get the default email
associated with the android phone and use this email in C2DM.

is it possible to use this email for using C2DM.. if yes then how should i get default email of android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot get which email is associated with the device and secondly you dont need client email you only need a registered email for sending C2DM notification but the condition is that you must have gmail account logged in on android

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand.  You do not send C2DM messages to an email address, you send to a RegistrationID that the C2DM library issued to a copy of your application registered on a device.  The only email address you need is your sender.

For reference: [C2DM documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)

Comment: oh you are great.. i was thinking that i need individual account for each device on which my application will be installed. now i got the point..  but i still have one confusion that where come this RegistrationID and is it different for each device on which my application will be installed

Comment: When your app runs on the device, it should send an Intent to the C2DM library to get a Registration ID.  You should then contact your web application server and pass it the Registration ID that C2DM gave to your client, along with whatever information you need to identify the user.  Store that ID, and use it to send messages to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the users email for C2DM. This email address you have to specify is an address of yours. Have a look at the chrome2phone source - it is a good example for C2DM http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/